# What is the solution to this NavigationStack glitch?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I've encountered a strange glitch with `NavigationStack` when mixing the old-style `NavigationLink` with the new `.navigationDestination` style ones. While this example is trivial and easily fixed here, in my larger project, I can't convert everything at once. As a result, there are instances where both styles are used within the same NavigationStack.

The following preview demonstrates the issue: You'll tap 'One', then 'Two', expecting a transition to 'Three'. However, instead of 'Three', 'Two' reappears. This cycle continues indefinitely if 'Two' is repeatedly tapped.

When navigating back, the strange behaviour continues, and we see 'Three' appearing at each transition on the way back out.

Any ideas on this very peculiar bug?

```
#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        NavigationLink("One") {
            NavigationLink("Two", value: 1)
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
                    Text("Three")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is by design. Value-based navigation just doesn't work with destination-based navigation. What would the navigation path look like when you are at "Three"? There should be 2 elements, but what would be the value corresponding to "Two"?  The behaviour that SwiftUI went with, is to always put the destination-based destination on the top of the stack.

Comment: It should be an error then, rather than this bizarre broken behaviour.

Comment: If you use a Text, Button or **any other View** other then `NavigationLink` to append something to the `path` (if you happen to use one) it will work fine. It is the NavigationLink that is causing the issue I guess.  `NavigationLink("One")` can remain. Replace only the inner one. This won't work directly in the `preview` though. So try it in an actual View.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug, a report to Apple is more appropriate than a workaround.

I was going to suggest a wrapper than can quickly convert the old

```
NavigationLink(
    _ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey,
    @ViewBuilder destination: () -> Destination
)
```

to

```
func navigationDestination<V>(
    isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
    @ViewBuilder destination: () -> V
) -> some View where V : View
```

The behavior still exists. It seems like "Two" gets pushed over "Three" every time.

I added some `navigationTitle` to visualize what was going on.

You can notice that the `Back` button switches to "Three` when clicking on Three but Two is shown in the content.

Here is the code I used.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewNavigationStack: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLinkTemp("One") {
                NavigationLink("Two", value: 1)
                    .navigationTitle("Two")
                    .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
                        Text("Three")
                            .navigationTitle("Three")
                    }
                
            }.navigationTitle("One")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NewNavigationStack()
}

struct NavigationLinkTemp<Destination: View>: View {
    let titleKey: LocalizedStringKey
    let destination: Destination
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    init(
        _ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey,
        @ViewBuilder destination: () -> Destination
    ){
        self.titleKey = titleKey
        self.destination = destination()
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button(titleKey) {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            destination
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe, a different navigation strategy  can be a solution to the problem however comes with "no guarentees", example using button:

```
NavigationStack {
    Button("One") {
        // ssome view
    }
    .navigationDestination {
        Button("Two") {
            //  view 2
        }
        .navigationDestination {
            Text("Three")
        }
    }
}
```

---

or Use programmatic navigation with case-switch logic

```
enum Destination {
    case one, two, three
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = [Destination]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Button("One") {
                path.append(.one)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                case .one:
                    Button("Two") {
                        path.append(.two)
                    }
                case .two:
                    Button("Three") {
                        path.append(.three)
                    }
                case .three:
                    Text("Three")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is no longer using any old-style NavigationLink though.

Comment: yes, in ways it wont allow to fall prey to its internal machinery, which i believe wont work very well with deeper layers UIs. think it like HTML, things get obsolete every year or 2 for newer standards proposed by WWC. regards